# How to access element in React JS that render by JS plugin

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mouse, mouseover

Is there a way to access the HTML element that rendered by JS plugin in React JS Ecosystem. I can't use ref on those elements.

**for example:-** If I use React Slick plugin, It adds many HTML elements that can't access by React JS. I need to trigger a mouse hover event on those elements.

Does anyone have a solution for this kind of situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the `id` of the container div that wraps the `<Slider/>` component is called `container` then the following code should work in attaching the `mouseover` event to all the nodes (divs in the slider):

```
    componentDidMount(){
       let nodes = document.getElementsById("container").childNodes[0].childNodes
       nodes.forEach(node => {
           node.addEventListener('mouseover', () => { 
              //action to be performed here
           }
       })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will help

```
componentdidmount{
  const elemnts = [...document.getElemetntByClassName('ClassName')]
  elements.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  // your code here
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Plugins has their own class and id. You can always inspect and customize the class they are using. But this may cause global changes. What you can do is to use custom class and selectors for separate components. Then you can make any changes in the css.